# Sending message to iPhone app like pushnotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, push-notification

In my iPhone app, there need to be a server request when user get a message from other user. For this currently I am using apple's push notification method and if I get a particular notification I will send the refresh request. But it will not work if a user disabled push notification for my app.

Is there any way to know server send a particular messsage to me ?
I know that sending request in every small time interval is not a proper way.

Comment: You can take a look at PubNub I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree push notifications are not the way to go.  You've already run into one issue and that's that the user can turn them off.  The other issue is that pushes are a best effort type of thing and there is no guarantee the user will get it, plus theres not much of a debug system to know if a message was delivered or not.  I'd suggest checking out a protocol called mqtt http://mqtt.org/, there are several iOS specific libraries that do all the work for you (of course you need to set it up on your back end as well).

Answer (score 0):

Use xmpp chat server. It is very easy to integrate also.

You can use openfire for integrating xmpp server. Or you can use any jabber client server like google yahoo.

You can make the communication between browser and iOS as well.

iOS code is also available.

[Openfire link](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)

[iOS Code](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

The main advantages of using XMPP server are:

1. You don't have to depend on push
2. It is super fast
3. Reliable
4. Easy to implement
5. You can add group chat and many more